# Custom Biome by Y level minecraft datapack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I would like anywhere under y28 in the nether to be a custom biome called "nether_depths". I tried using code from the deep dark (since it only spawns deep in the world), but it does not seem to work. How do I change the Y level of biomes?

Comment: Shouldnt this be in game dev or StackOverflow site?

Comment: No, this is not actually about code, custom world generation works with JSON files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out myself. First, you can set a custom check through use of a density_function with the following value:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:range_choice",
  "input": "minecraft:y",
  "min_inclusive": -32,
  "max_exclusive": 32,
  "when_in_range": 1,
  "when_out_of_range": 0
}
```

In this case, -32 to +32 will pass the check with a value of 1, otherwise the value will be 0.

Then in your corresponding noise_settings file (nether in this case) have depth reference your file (which I called depths): `"depth": "minecraft:nether/depths"`

Then finally, to add the biome, it's actually not done in noise_settings as I initially expected. It is instead done in the dimension folder. With something to the effect of the following:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:the_nether",
  "generator": {
    "type": "minecraft:noise",
    "settings": "minecraft:nether",
    "biome_source": {
      "type": "minecraft:multi_noise",
      "biomes": [
        {
          "biome": "minecraft:nether_wastes",
          "parameters": {
            "continentalness": 0.0,
            "depth": 0,
            "erosion": 0.0,
            "humidity": 0.0,
            "offset": 0.0,
            "temperature": 0.0,
            "weirdness": 0.0
          }
        },
        {
          "biome": "minecraft:soul_sand_valley",
          "parameters": {
            "continentalness": 0.0,
            "depth": 0,
            "erosion": 0.0,
            "humidity": -0.5,
            "offset": 0.0,
            "temperature": 0.0,
            "weirdness": 0.0
          }
        },
        {
          "biome": "minecraft:crimson_forest",
          "parameters": {
            "continentalness": 0.0,
            "depth": 0,
            "erosion": 0.0,
            "humidity": 0.0,
            "offset": 0.0,
            "temperature": 0.4,
            "weirdness": 0.0
          }
        },
        {
          "biome": "minecraft:warped_forest",
          "parameters": {
            "continentalness": 0.0,
            "depth": 0,
            "erosion": 0.0,
            "humidity": 0.5,
            "offset": 0.375,
            "temperature": 0.0,
            "weirdness": 0.0
          }
        },
        {
          "biome": "minecraft:basalt_deltas",
          "parameters": {
            "continentalness": 0.0,
            "depth": 0,
            "erosion": 0.0,
            "humidity": 0.0,
            "offset": 0.175,
            "temperature": -0.5,
            "weirdness": 0.0
          }
        },
        {
          "biome": "minecraft:nether_depths",
          "parameters": {
            "temperature": -0.6,
            "humidity": 0.0,
            "continentalness": 0.0,
            "erosion": 0.0,
            "weirdness": 0.0,
            "depth": 1,
            "offset": 0.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how depth is set to 0 for all biomes except my custom one. That means it is most likely out of any other biome to get placed between my specified y values (-32 to +32) as its depth value matches the value from the check while the others do not.